# Vertically oriented sentence on margins

Tags: vertical-alignment

I am writing a document and I would like to put a vertically oriented sentence on all page margins except the table of contents page.

my code is :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\makeatletter
\newlength\@tempdim@x
\newlength\@tempdim@y
% structure des commandes :
%   #1 = deplacement selon x
%   #2 = deplacement selon y
%   #3 = texte à mettre
\newcommand\AtUpperLeftCorner[3]{%
\begingroup
\@tempdim@x=0cm
\@tempdim@y=\paperheight
\advance\@tempdim@x#1
\advance\@tempdim@y-#2
\put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@x},\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@y}){#3}%
\endgroup
}
\newcommand\AtUpperRightCorner[3]{%
\begingroup
\@tempdim@x=\paperwidth
\@tempdim@y=\paperheight
\advance\@tempdim@x-#1
\advance\@tempdim@y-#2
\put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@x},\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@y}){#3}%
\endgroup
}
\newcommand\AtLowerLeftCorner[3]{%
\begingroup
\@tempdim@x=0cm
\@tempdim@y=0cm
\advance\@tempdim@x#1
\advance\@tempdim@y#2
\put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@x},\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@y}){#3}%
\endgroup
}
\newcommand\AtLowerRightCorner[3]{%
\begingroup
\@tempdim@x=\paperwidth
\@tempdim@y=0cm
\advance\@tempdim@x-#1
\advance\@tempdim@y#2
\put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@x},\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@y}){#3}%
\endgroup
}

\AddToShipoutPicture{%
    \AtLowerRightCorner{2cm}{5cm}{\ifodd\c@page\ifnum\arabic{page}>1 \rotatebox{90}{Good \raisebox{0.1ex}{--} My book}\fi\fi}
    \AtLowerLeftCorner{2cm}{5cm}{\ifodd\c@page\else\ifnum\arabic{page}>1 \rotatebox{90}{Good \raisebox{0.1ex}{--} My book}\fi\fi}
}
\makeatother

\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{document}
    {\pagestyle{plain}
    \tableofcontents}

\chapter{Chapter one}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{one}
\lipsum[2]
\section{two}
\lipsum[4]
\section{three}
\lipsum[11]
\chapter{Chapter two}
\section{four}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place an if with the value of the page:

```
\AddToShipoutPicture{%
\AtLowerRightCorner{2cm}{5cm}{\ifodd\c@page\ifnum\value{page}>1 \rotatebox{90}{Good \raisebox{0.1ex}{--} My book}\fi\fi}
\AtLowerLeftCorner{2cm}{5cm}{\ifodd\c@page\else\ifnum\value{page}>1 \rotatebox{90}{Good \raisebox{0.1ex}{--} My book}\fi\fi}
}
```

If you want you may define a counter and set it to the page number after the table of contents is printed and add this value to automate the process (May be will be a little bit more complex because the table of contents is been printed after the second compilation.).

**Edit:** (A workaround with the `mainmatter` stuff)

```
\newcounter{realpage}

\AddToShipoutPicture{%
\AtLowerRightCorner{2cm}{5cm}{\ifodd\c@page\ifnum\value{realpage}>0 \rotatebox{90}{Good \raisebox{0.1ex}{--} My book}\fi\fi}
\AtLowerLeftCorner{2cm}{5cm}{\ifodd\c@page\else\ifnum\value{realpage}>0 \rotatebox{90}{Good \raisebox{0.1ex}{--} My book}\fi\fi}
} 

\let\oldmainmatter\mainmatter
\def\mainmatter{\oldmainmatter\stepcounter{realpage}}
```

**Last Edit:**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\makeatletter
\newlength\@tempdim@x
\newlength\@tempdim@y
% structure des commandes :
%   #1 = deplacement selon x
%   #2 = deplacement selon y
%   #3 = texte à mettre
\newcommand\AtUpperLeftCorner[3]{%
\begingroup
\@tempdim@x=0cm
\@tempdim@y=\paperheight
\advance\@tempdim@x#1
\advance\@tempdim@y-#2
\put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@x},\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@y}){#3}%
\endgroup
}
\newcommand\AtUpperRightCorner[3]{%
\begingroup
\@tempdim@x=\paperwidth
\@tempdim@y=\paperheight
\advance\@tempdim@x-#1
\advance\@tempdim@y-#2
\put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@x},\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@y}){#3}%
\endgroup
}
\newcommand\AtLowerLeftCorner[3]{%
\begingroup
\@tempdim@x=0cm
\@tempdim@y=0cm
\advance\@tempdim@x#1
\advance\@tempdim@y#2
\put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@x},\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@y}){#3}%
\endgroup
}
\newcommand\AtLowerRightCorner[3]{%
\begingroup
\@tempdim@x=\paperwidth
\@tempdim@y=0cm
\advance\@tempdim@x-#1
\advance\@tempdim@y#2
\put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@x},\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@y}){#3}%
\endgroup
}

\newcounter{realpage}

\AddToShipoutPicture{%
\AtLowerRightCorner{2cm}{5cm}{\ifodd\c@page\ifnum\value{realpage}>0 \rotatebox{90}{Good \raisebox{0.1ex}{--} My book}\fi\fi}
\AtLowerLeftCorner{2cm}{5cm}{\ifodd\c@page\else\ifnum\value{realpage}>0 \rotatebox{90}{Good \raisebox{0.1ex}{--} My book}\fi\fi}
} 
\makeatother

\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{document}
    {\pagestyle{plain}
    \tableofcontents}



\chapter{Chapter one}
\stepcounter{realpage}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{one}
\lipsum[2]
\section{two}
\lipsum[4]
\section{three}
\lipsum[11]
\chapter{Chapter two}
\section{four}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

with the same preamble ... in order to print the vertical text in the upcoming possibly empty page after the toc use like this:

```
\begin{document}
    {\pagestyle{plain}
    \tableofcontents}
    \clearpage
    \stepcounter{realpage}

\chapter{Chapter one}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{one}
\lipsum[2]
\section{two}
\lipsum[4]
\section{three}
\lipsum[11]
\chapter{Chapter two}
\section{four}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am trying to use this solution but my table of contents page numbers are in raman and when I put the value (ii) I get errors.

Comment: Value is roman as far as I know ... means number... but you can replace my `\value` to `\arabic` ... not sure if this will work with page 2 existing twice ... But we could work arround this if you add the missing part of code in your MWE

Comment: @moumou85 ... Please check the edited solution...

Comment: I am trying to use \arabic but noway.

Comment: i changed my code in top (in my quation)

Comment: I use \newcounter{realpage} not work

Comment: Check last edit ... It doesn't print in second page too...

Comment: I do not know why

Comment: @moumou85 What do you mean? ... Do you want the vertical text to be printed in the next empty page after the toc? if so ... use the last code for the document environment.

Comment: I want  the vertical text to be printed in the all page of my document except the table of contents and the pages before table of contents.

Comment: use the last code ... (but table of contents in book contains a `\cleardoublepage` that means you are still in table of contents after it is printed... and possibly my \clearpage will give a problem if toc is finishing in an even page)

Comment: can I use special formatted for my TOC?

Comment: Checked the code for even pages and it is ok ... repeated `\clear` commands are ok. No problem with the last code. About your last comment... you can... my addition will not affect or be affected from the style of toc as far as it still contains or been followed by a `\cleardoublepage` as supposed to.

Comment: yes TOC i corrected it in my comment

Comment: The last code work very good, i will try it in my real document. thank you very mutche @ koleygr

Answer (score 1):

You can also manually set a flag to turn the overlay on and off.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\makeatletter
\newlength\@tempdim@x
\newlength\@tempdim@y
% structure des commandes :
%   #1 = deplacement selon x
%   #2 = deplacement selon y
%   #3 = texte à mettre
\newcommand\AtUpperLeftCorner[3]{%
\begingroup
\@tempdim@x=0cm
\@tempdim@y=\paperheight
\advance\@tempdim@x#1
\advance\@tempdim@y-#2
\put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@x},\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@y}){#3}%
\endgroup
}
\newcommand\AtUpperRightCorner[3]{%
\begingroup
\@tempdim@x=\paperwidth
\@tempdim@y=\paperheight
\advance\@tempdim@x-#1
\advance\@tempdim@y-#2
\put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@x},\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@y}){#3}%
\endgroup
}
\newcommand\AtLowerLeftCorner[3]{%
\begingroup
\@tempdim@x=0cm
\@tempdim@y=0cm
\advance\@tempdim@x#1
\advance\@tempdim@y#2
\put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@x},\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@y}){#3}%
\endgroup
}
\newcommand\AtLowerRightCorner[3]{%
\begingroup
\@tempdim@x=\paperwidth
\@tempdim@y=0cm
\advance\@tempdim@x-#1
\advance\@tempdim@y#2
\put(\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@x},\LenToUnit{\@tempdim@y}){#3}%
\endgroup
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% start edit %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newif\iftoc 

\AddToShipoutPicture{%
    \AtLowerRightCorner{2cm}{5cm}{\ifodd\c@page\iftoc\else \rotatebox{90}{Good \raisebox{0.1ex}{--} My book}\fi\fi}
    \AtLowerLeftCorner{2cm}{5cm}{\ifodd\c@page\else\iftoc\else \rotatebox{90}{Good \raisebox{0.1ex}{--} My book}\fi\fi}
}
\makeatother

\pagenumbering{roman}
\begin{document}
    {\pagestyle{plain}
    \global\toctrue% or place outside braces
    \tableofcontents}

\chapter{Chapter one}\tocfalse
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{one}
\lipsum[2]
\section{two}
\lipsum[4]
\section{three}
\lipsum[11]
\chapter{Chapter two}
\section{four}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @John Kormylo it work perfectly.